# Prediction values ​​of the vector

Tags: self-study

Given a length-n vector (the elements of vector describe samples of any time changes).

There are $m$ elements​​, and other values $n-m$ (coming right after the first n elements)

I need to predict what their value of other $n-m$ elements​​ .

I would like to know which **prediction method** is recommended to use for solving the above problem?

**for example:**

```
%create vector of sampling
Fs= 1/200;
n=200;
m=50;
t=0:Fs:2*pi;
x=sin(t);


%call prediction function 
fprediction(x, Fs ,m); % x:vector, Fs: frequency sampling, m:number of element to predict
...
```

I need to predict what their value of other n−m (**50**) elements, relying only on the first 150 elements​​ .

Comment:

The use in sampling rate to resolve the problem  is optional

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [Autoregressive model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model). It's very appropriate for harmonic signals.

Comment: I was thinking to use in the following method  [Linear prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_prediction). Is to calculate the values ​​of a (i) I need only use the first n values ​​(without remaining m)?

Comment: Surely, you use only known values while fitting any model to your data.